# why is a negative long value greater than a positive unsigned long value?

Tags: c, long-integer, unsigned-integer

Example code:

```
long num1 = -1;
unsigned long num2 = 1;

if (num1 > num2)
    printf("Num1 is greater\n");
else
    printf("Num2 is greater\n");
```

Why does this evaluate num1 > num2 as true instead of it being false?

Comment: Don't mix signed and unsigned!!!

Comment: @DeiDei The standard allows you to mix signed and unsigned, as long as you understand and follow the rules defined by the language standard. The code is not easy to understand, but it is fully defined by the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the result of an integer promotion rule described in C99 standard, section 6.3.1.8:

> if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.

This is exactly what happens in your example: `long` and `unsigned long` have the same rank, so the signed `long` is converted to `unsigned long`.

Since `-1` cannot be represented as an unsigned, the following rules come into play:

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

The result is, therefore, `1- + ULONG_MAX-1`, which equals `ULONG_MAX`. That is why the result of converting `-1` to `unsigned` is greater than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

When using a `long` and `unsigned long` together in an expression, the ‘long`value is converted to`unsigned long`.  This results in the value -1 becoming the largest`unsigned long` value, which is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two variables of different data types, i.e. **long** & **unsigned long**.

In this case, during comparison of two variables, compiler is **implicitly typecasting** the variable **num1** to **unsigned long** as two variables of different data types can't be compared.

So, **num1** is being converted to **65534** [65535 - 1].

Thus, you are getting **Num1 is greater**